# strcat with char pointers

Tags: c++, strcat

So, my problem is simple, I whant to create a function to separate the words in the file and parse those words and create an special think for those words, but, I have an error in strcat, when I try to separate the tokens:

look the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool compile(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;
    char token[256];
    bool _return = false;

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(isalpha(c))
        {
                    // The error is here
            strcat(token, (char*)c);
            printf("%c\n", c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("----> %c\n", c);
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", token);

    return _return;
}

int main()
{
    char *filename = "test.in";

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(!fp)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(!compile(fp))
    {
        printf("ERROR...\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

THe code builds normally, but, when I debug, the debugger goes to strcat.asm file :(
So, where is my error, thanks for the help. (:

-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-> edit
And, when I change the strcat to:

```
strcat(token, &c)
```

I receive this error from the debugger:

> Unhandled exception at 0x20E801F2 in APP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation (parameters: 0x00000008).

Comment: token is uninitialized.  Try `token[0] = 0;` before entering the loop.

Comment: But casting a char to `char*` is meaningless, so you're still broken.

Comment: and you can't strcat a character. so either do token[1] = 0; before the strcat. Or replace the strcat with token[token_len++] = c; token[token_len] = 0; But check you don't exceed token's buffer size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat` expects a null-terminated string; you cannot pass a pointer to an individual character and expect it to work correctly.

Replace

```
strcat(token, (char*)c);
```

with

```
char tmp[2];
tmp[0] = c;
tmp[1] = '\0';
strcat(token, tmp);
```

to make it work.

You also need to set `token[0]` to zero to avoid undefined behavior due to it not being initialized.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You are right, the latest C++ standard has changed that (PODs used to be zero-initialized per the old standard). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
strcat(token, (char *) c);
```

The variable `c` isn't a string, it's only a single character.  The cast to `(char *)` is just masking a compiler error.

If you want to add characters to a string one at a time,

```
std::size_t pos = 0;
char buf[256];

// ...

if (isalpha(c)) {
    assert(pos < sizeof(buf));
    buf[pos++] = c;
}

// ...

assert(pos < sizeof(buf));
buf[pos] = '\0';
printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
```

Or, you know, do it the easy way:

```
#include <string>

std::string s;

// ...

if (isalpha(c)) {
    s += c;
}

// ...

printf("buf = %s\n", s.c_str());
```

Don't bother to debug the insides of `strcat()`.  If your program crashes inside `strcat()`, it is an error in the calling function.  (It's usually an error to even call `strcat()` at all.)

Answer (score 2):

When you cast `c` to `char *`, you're turning whatever value was in the character (say `100` in hexadecimal) into a memory address (`0x100`) and then looking for a string at that memory address.  No wonder it doesn't work!  You'll want to turn the character into a string before popping it into `strcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- You don't check if you overflow the 256 characters in your buffer
- When you convert `char c` to `(char *) c` you are saying that c is a memory address. In actuality, it is a value. What you probably want is a reference to the character, `&c`
- You need to add a null terminator to the end of what you are concatenating.